# Python Shebang Doesn't Work #!/usr/local/bin/python

Tags: python, shell, shebang

I am trying to use Crontab to schedule a shell script that runs the main python script. I had tried putting shebang `#!/usr/local/bin/python` in the first line of python script but it errorred out with "cannot importing certain packages". However, if I call the python script in the shell script by `/usr/local/bin/python  python_script.py`, it worked. Any ideas why I can't use the shebang `#!/usr/local/bin/python` directly in python instead of the way calling in the shell as mentioned above (it's not elegant)?

Comment: It is helpful to give the error message instead of just saying "it errored out". It sounds like you don't have the execute bit set on the script.

Comment: If you’re running as root from cron, you probably are getting different packages (assumingly user-local packages).

Comment: Good ol "cannot importing certain packages"

Comment: Either pip install all deps as root, or — much better — create a virtual environment, install everything you need there and then call your script with interpreter from the virtual env’s bin dir. E.g. /path/to/venv/bin/python.

Comment: The shell started by crond probably has different environemnt variables from the one that you as a user has.  I second @randomir.

Comment: @janm The reason I didn't give the error message is because I don't think it's relevant. Just FYI, the exact error message is `ImportError: cannot import name Counter`.

Comment: @lovechillcool, can you please include the relevant import statements in your question? Also, have you tried with the virtualenv suggestion?

Comment: @randomir Isn't the Shebang in python script `#!/usr/local/bin/python` calling the script from virtual env? What should be the correct syntax of using the virtual env?

Comment: @lovechillcool, no. Unless you created a virtual env rooted at `/usr/local` -- which is highly unlikely. If your virtual env is rooted at `/home/user/project/env`, then use `/home/user/project/env/bin/python` as interpreter in the hashbang.

Comment: @randomir But why I was able to run the shell as `/usr/local/bin/python  python_script.py`?

Comment: Because you weren't running the script as `root` (as cron does), but under your user. When you run as root, packages installed with `pip install --user` are not available anymore.

Comment: It can't be your shebang line because it would not be getting as far as the `ImportError` if that was the case.  Do you have any settings, like `PYTHONPATH` in your startup files, e.g. `.bash_profile`, `.profile`, `.bashrc`?   `cron` jobs don't read startup files and many issues with `cron` are because of this.  If so then write a wrapper shell script which sources these files and the calls your python script.

Answer (score 0):

This is very likely an issue with your environment variables. Most likely you've got different entries in your `PATH` or `PYTHONPATH` variables.

To see the difference, you could have your script be a bash script and have it echo the output of `env` and compare it to your shell's `env`.